# R studio: could not find function

Tags: r

[image]

All I did was change v1 tot v2 in the function name, both in the function call as in the script of the function itself, as well as in the file name of the function (.R).

Wd is correctly set and I can see the v2 file in there from within the R studio console and I can find it in explorer. However I get this error:

```
Error in calculate_depreciation_percentage_v2(end_of_life_value_perc_temp,  : 
  could not find function "calculate_depreciation_percentage_v2"
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Maybe with onedrive one has to do something special to allow R to acces? But it can access all my other functions in the same directory.. .

Comment: when I change it back to v1, it says source is not available so debug location is is approximate...

Comment: When you run `getwd()` do you get the path location where the .R file is located?